# Neo4j server failed to start

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-12.04

Tried starting neo4j service and got a message like

> WARNING: Detected a limit of 1024 for maximum open files, while a
>   minimum value of 40000 is recommended.
>   WARNING: Problems with the
>   operation of the server may occur. Please refer to the Neo4j manual
>   regarding lifting this limitation. Starting Neo4j Server...
>   WARNING:
>   not changing user  process [17348]... waiting for server to be
>   ready... BAD. Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the
>   logs.

The log says :

```
Opened [/home/ub/graph_db/neo4j-community-1.7.M01/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1] clean empty log, version=224, lastTxId=654769
2013-03-14 11:26:28.111+0000: TM opening log: /home/ub/graph_db/neo4j-community-1.7.M01/data/graph.db/tm_tx_log.1
2013-03-14 11:26:28.159+0000: Failed to load index provider lucene Target file[lucene.log.v318] already exists
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Target file[lucene.log.v318] already exists
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils.renameFile(FileUtils.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.renameFile(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.renameLogFileToRightVersion(XaLogicalLog.java:700)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.renameIfExists(XaLogicalLog.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:171)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.<init>(LuceneDataSource.java:229)
    at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneIndexProvider.load(LuceneIndexProvider.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader.loadIndexImplementations(AbstractGraphDatabase.java:986)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader.init(AbstractGraphDatabase.java:958)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase.run(AbstractGraphDatabase.java:178)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoServerBootstrapper$1.createDatabase(NeoServerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.Database.createDatabase(Database.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.Database.<init>(Database.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoServerWithEmbeddedWebServer.startDatabase(NeoServerWithEmbeddedWebServer.java:186)
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoServerWithEmbeddedWebServer.start(NeoServerWithEmbeddedWebServer.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:52)
2013-03-14 11:26:28.160+0000: TM shutting down
2013-03-14 11:26:28.382+0000: Closed log /home/biju/graph_db/neo4j-community-1.7.M01/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log
2013-03-14 11:26:28.945+0000: NeoStore closed
2013-03-14 11:26:28.946+0000: --- SHUTDOWN diagnostics START ---
2013-03-14 11:26:28.947+0000: --- SHUTDOWN diagnostics END ---
```

This started happening when I have installed ElasticSearch on my machine. There was one issue with  starting Elastic search "JAVA_HOME issue", which is sorted.

Comment: This issue is fixed in the current stable version 1.8.2 I recommend that you upgrade.

Comment: Actually why this issue came up suddenly? Was it due to the elastic search installation.
So, to resolve this issue I need to upgrade is the only solution? :(

Comment: @MichaelHunger upgraded to 1.8.2 still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a db with that problem, upgrading won't make it go away. 1.8.2 will prevent this from happening though. You're running community I see so keeping old logs around isn't all that necessary. Try deleting the existing lucene.log.v318 file, or move it away at least and see what happens the next startup.

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem when I was installing Neo4j the first time on my Linux laptop, I solved putting this couple of rows at the end of the */etc/security/limits.conf* file:

```
user               hard    nofile          100000
user               soft    nofile          40000
```

where *user* is the login name of the user who starts Neo4j.
The *10000* and *40000* are somewhat arbirtrary, they were ok for me, in case you still get the error try to increase them.

Comment: I tried increasing them but didn't solve the issue. Thanks for the help.